# Understanding some concepts

Tags: java, oop, generics, methods, constructor

I am new to java and am trying to understand the following code piece.

```
public class Foo extends Bar<Type, Type2> {

  @Override
  public SomeFoo<Type, Type2> getReader(Type type) throws IOException {
    return new SomeInstance(type);
  }
}
```

I am trying to understand what is `public SomeFoo`.

Its not a class?? is it a constructor.. why does it returns something?

When I will do

```
Foo foobar = new Foo()
```

What will be `foobar`?

And what is `Bar<Type,type2>`? Why do we use these arrow brackets?

Comment: Hm. Start [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/).

Comment: I think the OP needs to start earlier than generics. [Here perhaps](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/index.html)

Comment: @BoristheSpider: I see that generics answer the second query but what is public SomeFoo ?

Comment: `public someFoo(...)`is just a plain public Method returning an instance of another class `someInstance` - usually used on inner classes with only some static methods.

Comment: @AndrewGibson I thought the question was "what is the generic type of `foobar`", but it seems you are right. Java basics first, then generics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`public SomeFoo<Type, Type2> getReader(Type type)` is an inherited method from the `Bar` class.  We know it is inherited from `Bar` because of the use of `extends` in the class definition.

`Foo foobar = new Foo()` creates a `Foo` object and `foobar` is the means to reference that object.

The brackets `<>` represent what is known as a generic in Java.

It is beyond the scope of this thread to get into the details of what generics are and how they operate.  I'd recommend, like others, to read up on them here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html

Comment: This only answers half the question; and not very well at that.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I'm not an expert at java, just trying to give the guy some help based on what I know.  Thanks for the insult, tho.

Answer (score 2):

The **SomeFoo<Type,Type2>** is a type. This particular one is using Java generics, here is some more information about it: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html.

Also **Bar<Type,Type2>** is a type, here the base class of the class Foo. The arrow brackets are used to make classes generic to spare duplicates. Think it it like you have list of boolean values. How will this list differ from a list integer values? Here only the type of entries are different, so programming languages allows us to abstract from it:

```
List<Boolean> booleans = ...;
List<Integer> integers = ...;
```

See the Javadoc and/or Source for the class **java.util.List** to learn more about this.

Answer (score 1):

From the definition, we know we have two generic classes:

Bar:

```
public class Bar<T, V> {...}
```

and SomeFoo:

```
public class SomeFoo<T, V> {...}
```

Foo represents a class which is no longer generic.  In other words, T and V have been fixed as Type and Type2.  So if you want to make a Foo, you can use new Foo() instead of new Foo.

SomeFoo is another object with generics, which should also be fixed as Type and Type2 within Foo. So SomeFoo is the return type of the public method getReader(Type type).